# Change CSS's default vw size?

Tags: html, css

is there a way in CSS that I can modify the default value of the 'vw' (view width) ?

Example: My real viewport's width is 1920 and I want to set an element's width to 1650px, but with the value of 100vw.Is there a way in CSS that I can modify the default value of the 'vw' (view width)?

Comment: No, you can't make `100vw` be anything but the viewport width, though you can block an elements width by giving it a `max-width`, as shown in _dippas_ answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can, just set `max-width:1650px`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

div {
  background: red;
  max-width: 1650px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```